# Explicitly checking independence for more than 2 random variables

Tags: probability

I understand that a set of events is mutually independent if every event is independent of any intersection of the other events. But, I've been told I don't need to explicitly check this for random variables; in other words, a single condition $$P(X_1 \leq x_1, X_2 \leq x_2, \cdots, X_n \leq x_n) = P(X_1 \leq x_1)P(X_2 \leq x_2)... P(X_n \leq x_n)$$ checks all that.

Can someone explain why?

Specifically, I'm confused by this paragraph

[image]

Comment: That is not a single condition.  It is an infinite number of conditions that must hold for all $x_1, ..., x_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book's explanation is unclear-to-confusing: the second-to-last sentence is oblique, while the last sentence is not even relevant to the point.

Let $S$ be the sample sapce. Then the condition $$P(X_1 \leq x_1\cap X_2 \leq x_2\cap \ldots\cap X_n \leq x_n) = P(X_1 \leq x_1)P(X_2 \leq x_2)\ldots P(X_n \leq x_n)$$ includes all the random-variable combinations because, for example,

- when $P(X_3\leq x_3),\ldots,(X_n\leq x_n)=1,$ the condition becomes
  $$P(X_1 \leq x_1\cap X_2 \leq x_2\cap S\cap\ldots\cap S) = P(X_1 \leq
     x_1)P(X_2 \leq x_2)\times1\times\ldots\times1 \\P(X_1 \leq x_1\cap
     X_2 \leq x_2) = P(X_1 \leq x_1)P(X_2 \leq x_2),$$ which checks the
  pairwise independence of the random variables $X_1$ and $X_2.$